# WinForm c# not compiling after adding images to resources

Tags: c#, image, winforms, visual-studio

I'm working on a project that uses a large number of images (at least a couple hundred). If I try to add all of them to my resources at once and try to compile, it fails without giving me any error messages other than

> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I've tried removing each image one by one, to see if there's a single corrupt image messing it up, but I figured that wasn't the case. When I found what I believed what was the corrupt image file, removed it, and added it back, it would work fine. But if I add a bunch of images that should have been working fine, I get the same problem again. So is there any solution or workaround with dealing with a large number of image files?

Comment: If the compile is failing without errors, you're going to have to dive a bit to figure out what's breaking it. Open up your settings in Visual Studio and go to Projects and Solutions > Build and Run and set the MSBuild output/log verbosity to Detailed, and if that doesn't yield any new information, turn it up to Diagnostic.

Comment: Here's what i got after setting it to Detailed: 1>  Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Debug\Text_Simulator.Properties.Resources.resources".
1>Done executing task "GenerateResource" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: I take it you have done a clean and rebuild? May want to clear out your obj folder entirely anyways.

Comment: Yup, I've already tried cleaning and deleting the obj folder but still no results.